# How to match any empty OR non alphabetic symbol (python re)

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I want to write python re expression to match strings like "apple", "apple!", "apple." etc. However I don't want to match strings like "apples" or "appler".

How to do that? If I write r"apple[,! .-]*", it also matches "apples".

Basically I want to match "apple" + "end of string OR non-alphabetic symbol"

Comment: this should do `"apple\W"`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to match:

> "apple" + "end of string OR non-alphabetic symbol"

While *non-alphabetic symbol* means all the characters but not alphabets, we should be capable of matching the strings like `apple;_-_>:Z`, but not the strings like `appleZ;_-_>:`. That is, most likely equivalent to the case: **Any strings, that start with `apple` followed by any other characters than `abc...xyz` and `ABC...XYZ`**

In your case, that is: accepting `["apple", "apple!", "apple."]`, rejecting `["apples", "appler"]`.

We have several options of RE to achieve that. Accoding to [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), One option might be `(?!...)`, called *negative lookahead assertion*. The other one might be `[^...]`, called *complementing*.

The codes below provide a relatively simple implementation for your case.

```py
import re


def test_regex(list_should_match, list_should_NOT_match):
    regex = "^apple(?![a-zA-Z]).*$"       # lookahead.       recommended
    # regex="^apple[^a-zA-Z]*$"           # complementing.      works but less flexibility
    ptn = re.compile(regex)
    for str in list_should_match:
        if ptn.match(str) == None:
            return False
    for str in list_should_NOT_match:
        if ptn.match(str) != None:
            return False
    return True


# All cases you provided
list_should_match = ["apple", "apple!", "apple."]
list_should_NOT_match = ["apples", "appler"]
res = test_regex(list_should_match, list_should_NOT_match)
print("tests result:    %s" % ("PASS" if res else "X"))

# Some additional cases
list_should_match = ["apple;_-_>:Z", "apple,", "apple-",
                     "apple;", "apple[", "apple>123456789",
                     "apple123456789", "apple123456789ZZZ"]
list_should_NOT_match = ["appleZ;_-_>:", "appleABC", "appleZZZ;;;;"]
res = test_regex(list_should_match, list_should_NOT_match)
print("(additional)tests result:    %s" % ("PASS" if res else "X"))
```